# Convert PDF to image with high resolution

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I'm trying to use the command line program [`convert`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) to take a PDF into an image (JPEG or PNG). Here is [one of the PDFs](http://jonathanwhitmore.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/test.pdf) that I'm trying to convert.

I want the program to trim off the excess white-space and return a high enough quality image that the superscripts can be read with ease.

This is my current [best attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCjw6.jpg). As you can see, the trimming works fine, I just need to sharpen up the resolution quite a bit. This is the command I'm using:

```
convert -trim 24.pdf -resize 500% -quality 100 -sharpen 0x1.0 24-11.jpg
```

I've tried to make the following conscious decisions:

- resize it larger (has no effect on the resolution)
- make the quality as high as possible
- use the `-sharpen` (I've tried a range of values)

Any suggestions please on getting the resolution of the image in the final PNG/JPEG higher would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See also: http://askubuntu.com/a/50180/64957

Comment: If you're on a mac, have a look at the [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/sips.html) for `sips`, the "scriptable image processing system". It's a command line image editor built in to macOS, works on PDFs and many other image types.

Comment: @ghoti sips will only convert the first page of a PDF file to an image.

Comment: It is my understanding, that you can only “force” pdftoppm to a certain resolution (may result in down- or upscaling), no such thing as „just use original resolution of each contained image“, right?

Answer (score 482, accepted):

It appears that the following works:

```
convert           \
   -verbose       \
   -density 150   \
   -trim          \
    test.pdf      \
   -quality 100   \
   -flatten       \
   -sharpen 0x1.0 \
    24-18.jpg
```

It results in [**the left image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmLXI.jpg). Compare this to the result of my original command ([**the image on the right**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCjw6.jpg)):

[image]  [image]

(To ***really*** see and appreciate the differences between the two, right-click on each and select *"Open Image in New Tab..."*.)

Also keep the following facts in mind:

- The worse, blurry image on the right has a file size of 1.941.702 Bytes (1.85 MByte).
  Its resolution is 3060x3960 pixels, using 16-bit RGB color space.
- The better, sharp image on the left has a file size of 337.879 Bytes (330 kByte).
  Its resolution is 758x996 pixels, using 8-bit Gray color space.

So, no need to resize; add the `-density` flag. The density value 150 is weird -- trying a range of values results in a worse looking image in both directions!

Comment: The `density` parameter is a bit special in that in must come *before* the input file. As PDF is a vector based file format which does not have (much) notion of pixels, it says something like "page is 8in by 12in". If you want pixel, you use the `density` setting to tell it, how many pixels per inch you want to get in the output. E. g. with 150 you would get 8x150=1200 by 12x150=1800 pixels in the resulting image. That's also the amount of pixels the sharpen, contrast, compression etc. settings work on.

Comment: The sharpening works really well with black on white. However it deteriorates readability when there is black writing on grey background.

Comment: It can result in black background on Mac OS (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934456/imagemagick-pdf-to-jpgs-sometimes-results-in-black-background). To fix this, add `-flatten`.

Comment: i got a black background on Mac OS when I tried to convert pdf to png, adding -flatten solved it.

Comment: Wow! Just used the `-density` and `-flatten` option to reduce the size of a pdf (to another pdf). The `-flatten` option really helps a lot in reducing the total size. In my case, without visual disturbances.

Comment: The `-density` flag will likely give worse results on higher values if the quality of the starting image was lower than that.

Comment: @DanielSchneller I wish I saw your comment earlier. This little peculiarity took me half a day today.

Comment: Also if you need a particular page in the PDF, you can add an index to the end of the filename. (e.g. use `test.pdf[0]` for the first page, `test.pdf[1]` for the second, etc)

Comment: You might want to give `pdftoppm` a shot too. It supports many image file output types, cropping, resizing, etc, as well. I describe how to use it in my brand new answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58795684/4561887.

Comment: If you want convert multipage pdf, you should remove `-flatten` flag. Because it squash pages into one.

Comment: For those who got here looking for a php Imagick solution. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033954/set-density-parameter-for-imagick-with-php

Comment: Excellent!
But don't use the -flatten, and -trim options on multipage printable pdf conversion:
 -flatten - puts all pages over on a single image
 -trim - cuts the white margin up to the text

Answer (score 209):

Personally I like this.

```
convert -density 300 -trim test.pdf -quality 100 test.jpg
```

It's a little over twice the file size, but it looks better to me.

`-density 300` sets the dpi that the PDF is rendered at.

`-trim` removes any edge pixels that are the same color as the corner pixels.

`-quality 100` sets the JPEG compression quality to the highest quality.

Things like `-sharpen` don't work well with text because they undo things your font rendering system did to make it more legible.

If you actually want it blown up use resize here and possibly a larger dpi value of something like `targetDPI * scalingFactor`  That will render the PDF at the resolution/size you intend.

Descriptions of the parameters on imagemagick.org are [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php)

Comment: It's twice the size mostly because the output density has been doubled and the jpg compression quality is set on max (so not much compression).

Comment: Using `convert` how will we know how many pages got converted?

Comment: Uh, this is definitely the way to go. Bump up that source density and remove the `-sharpen`. The quality is much much better than with the defaults and way more natural than with `-sharpen`.

Comment: This should be the best answer, not the current one. Also, this is needed as well on Ubuntu: `mv /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xml /etc/ImageMagick-6/policy.xmlout` when convert fails (source: https://askubuntu.com/a/1081907)

Comment: @Meet please understand that your question is very specific and it's maybe too difficult to be explained here. Sadly I'm not sure where you can post such question. I hope somebody can help.

Comment: @Meet It's technically possible but ugly. Open the pdf in your pdf app (edge). Zoom in. Screenshot. Paste that into your image editor (paint). Drag the pdf image around. Repeat. It's ugly and time consuming really just installing imagemagick or graphicsmagick as a normal user is much easier. You don't even need to run the installer. Grab the zip and then extract it and run from that folder. No special permissions needed.

Answer (score 43):

I really haven't had good success with `convert` [update May 2020: actually: it pretty much never works for me], but I've had EXCELLENT success with `pdftoppm`. Here's a couple examples of producing high-quality images from a PDF:

1. [Produces ~25 MB-sized files per pg] Output uncompressed **.tif** file format at **300 DPI** into a folder called "images", with files being named **pg-1.tif**, **pg-2.tif**, **pg-3.tif**, etc:

   ```bash
   mkdir -p images && pdftoppm -tiff -r 300 mypdf.pdf images/pg
   ```
2. [Produces ~1MB-sized files per pg] Output in **.jpg** format at **300 DPI**:

   ```bash
   mkdir -p images && pdftoppm -jpeg -r 300 mypdf.pdf images/pg
   ```
3. [Produces ~2MB-sized files per pg] Output in **.jpg** format **at highest quality (least compression)** and still at **300 DPI**:

   ```bash
   mkdir -p images && pdftoppm -jpeg -jpegopt quality=100 -r 300 mypdf.pdf images/pg
   ```

#### For more explanations, options, and examples, [see my full answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1187844/327339).

### See also

1. My answer: [Ask Ubuntu: How to turn a PDF into a searchable PDF w/`pdf2searchablepdf`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1187881/327339)
2. My answer: [How to convert a PDF into JPG with command line in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61700520/4561887)
3. My answer: [Unix & Linux: pdf to jpg without quality loss; `gscan2pdf`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585574/114401)

Comment: related issue: [vector anti-aliasing: pdftoppm produces different result (darker, more black) than chromium PDF reader](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/poppler/poppler/-/issues/1423)

Answer (score 32):

I use `pdftoppm` on the command line to get the initial image, typically with a resolution of 300dpi, so `pdftoppm -r 300`, then use `convert` to do the trimming and PNG conversion.

Comment: while not using Imagemagick, this solution seems most in the spirit of a transparent conversion. `pdftoppm` can also output JPEGs and PNGs.

Comment: pdftoppm resulted in really nice JPEGs for me (and still smaller than IM)! Thanks!

Comment: It seems that without the '-r' flag, pdftoppm uses the native resolution of the pdf, which is the maximal resolution you can get out of the pdf. The convert tool keeps this resolution.

Comment: PNG results are superior compared to JPG: `pdftoppm -png -r 300` Or set the jpeg options with `-jpegopt quality=100`

Answer (score 24):

normally I extract the embedded image with 'pdfimages' at the native resolution, then use ImageMagick's convert to the needed format:

```
$ pdfimages -list fileName.pdf
$ pdfimages fileName.pdf fileName   # save in .ppm format
$ convert fileName-000.ppm fileName-000.png
```

this generate the best and smallest result file.

Note: For lossy JPG embedded images, you had to use -j:

```
$ pdfimages -j fileName.pdf fileName   # save in .jpg format
```

With recent "poppler-util" (0.50+, 2016) you can use -all that save lossy as jpg and lossless as png, so a simple:

```
$ pdfimages -all fileName.pdf fileName
```

extract always the best possible quality content from PDF.

On little provided Win platform you had to download a recent (0.68, 2018)  'poppler-util' binary from:
http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/

Comment: Just a minor correction: the second command in first code block should start with `pdftoppm`  not with `pdfimages`

Comment: no, older pdfimages saves extracted images to ppm like pdftoppm, and pdftoppm never had the -list option. Current pdfimages can directly save to PNG and JPG with -all as stated in the note

Comment: to get poppler on Windows, `msys2` is the best solution

Comment: take care that minimum MSYS2 installation is 400 MB, while http://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/ has an installer sized 7 MB

Comment: If the original pdf file is consisting of embedded images, this answer is relevant, but I think the OP example pdf consists of vectoral text, which are not embedded images. So, OP can not use this approach, imho. Thanks anyway for other use cases though.

Answer (score 21):

In ImageMagick, you can do "supersampling". You specify a large density and then resize down as much as desired for the final output size. For example with your image:

```
convert -density 600 test.pdf -background white -flatten -resize 25% test.png
```

[image]

Download the image to view at full resolution for comparison..

I do not recommend saving to JPG if you are expecting to do further processing.

If you want the output to be the same size as the input, then resize to the inverse of the ratio of your density to 72. For example, -density 288 and -resize 25%. 288=4*72 and 25%=1/4

The larger the density the better the resulting quality, but it will take longer to process.

Answer (score 16):

I have found it both faster and more stable when batch-processing large PDFs into PNGs and JPGs to use the underlying `gs` (aka Ghostscript) command that `convert` uses.

You can see the command in the output of `convert -verbose` and there are a few more tweaks possible there (YMMV) that are difficult / impossible to access directly via `convert`.

However, it would be harder to do your trimming and sharpening using `gs`, so, as I said, YMMV!

Answer (score 10):

It also gives you good results:

```
exec("convert -geometry 1600x1600 -density 200x200 -quality 100 test.pdf test_image.jpg");
```

Answer (score 7):

Linux user here: I tried the `convert` command-line utility (for PDF to PNG) and I was not happy with the results.  I found this to be easier, with a better result:

- extract the pdf page(s) with pdftk

  - e.g.: `pdftk file.pdf cat 3 output page3.pdf`
- open (import) that pdf with `GIMP`

  - important: change the import `Resolution` from `100` to `300` or `600 pixel/in`
- in `GIMP` export as PNG (change file extension to .png)

**Edit:**

Added picture, as requested in the `Comments`. Convert command used:

`convert -density 300 -trim struct2vec.pdf -quality 100 struct2vec.png`

`GIMP` : imported at 300 dpi (px/in); exported as PNG compression level 3.

I have not used GIMP on the command line (re: my comment, below).

[image: pdf2png]

[image]

Comment: Can this be automated if you have thousands of pages?

Comment: @JBWhitmore: good question.  Certainly it'd be simple to script the pdftk command, as it's already on the command line.  I did a really quick Google search, and found that GIMP has a batch mode (I haven't tried it, but it looks like that should be scriptable as well): https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/

Comment: Cool. Also, can you update your answer with side-by-side images of the accepted answer vs what you get with your approach?

Comment: @JBWhitmore an example script to automate this conversion is shown  on this question/answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121293/convert-every-pdf-in-the-current-directory-to-png

Comment: @tsherwen, If I read that link correctly it's how to automate the convert command. I'm not confused on how to do that. However, this answer says to use GIMP as one of the steps -- and neither this answer nor the linked appears to show how to automate that.

Comment: @JBWhitmore. I mistakenly was just thinking in terms of the question on ``convert``. I only saw the part of this answer mentioning ``convert`` and your question whilst reading your automation comment. Thanks for your answer later on this thread, which I combined with the solution I linked to and solved a different issue I was having.

Answer (score 3):

For **Windows** (tested on W11):

```
magick.exe -verbose -density 150 "input.pdf" -quality 100 -sharpen 0x1.0 output.jpg
```

**You need install:**

ImageMagick https://imagemagick.org/index.php

ghostscript
https://www.ghostscript.com/releases/gsdnld.html

**Additional info:**

- Watch for using `-flatten` parameter since it can produce only first page as image
- Use `-scene 1` parameter to start at index 1 with images names
- `convert` command mentioned in question has been deprecated in favor to `magick`

Answer (score 2):

One more suggestion is that you can use GIMP.

Just load the PDF file in GIMP->save as .xcf and then you can do whatever you want to the image.

Comment: The reason for doing this via the command line is that I had thousands of pages that needed this process.

Comment: Also, GIMP renders the page on *loading*, so you'll want to set the resolution when you select the pages to load. It doesn't much matter what you set the output parameters to if you start with the 100 DPI default on loading.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [pdf2image](https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/). A simple python library that works like charm.

First install [poppler](https://blog.alivate.com.au/poppler-windows/) on non linux machine. You can just download the zip. Unzip in Program Files and add bin to Machine Path.

After that you can use pdf2image in python class like this:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path, convert_from_bytes
images_from_path = convert_from_path(
   inputfile,
   output_folder=outputpath,
   grayscale=True, fmt='jpeg')
```

I am not good with python but was able to make exe of it.
Later you may use the exe with file input and output parameter. I have used it in C# and things are working fine.

Image quality is good. OCR works fine.

Edited:
Here is my another finding, You don't need to install Poppler for conversion.
Just make your converter.exe from Python and place it in binary bin folder of Poppler window.
I suppose it will work on azure aswell.

Answer (score 1):

```
convert -density 300 * airbnb.pdf
```

Looked perfect to me

Answer (score 0):

PNG file you attached looks really blurred. In case if you need to use additional post-processing for each image you generated as PDF preview, you will decrease performance of your solution.

[2JPEG](http://www.2jpeg.com) can convert PDF file you attached to a nice sharpen JPG and crop empty margins in one call:

```
2jpeg.exe -src "C:\In\*.*" -dst "C:\Out" -oper Crop method:autocrop
```

Comment: The blurriness in the original PNG is what inspired the question in the first place, and the PNG in the accepted answer is rather crisp.

Answer (score 0):

**Please take note before down voting, this solution is for Gimp using a graphical interface, and not for ImageMagick using a command line, but it worked perfectly fine for me as an alternative, and that is why I found it needful to share here.**

Follow these simple steps to extract images in any format from PDF documents

1. Download **GIMP Image Manipulation Program**
2. Open the Program after installation
3. Open the PDF document that you want to extract Images
4. Select only the pages of the PDF document that you would want to extract images from.
   N/B: If you need only the cover images, select only the first page.
5. Click open after selecting the pages that you want to extract images from
6. Click on **File** menu when GIMP when the pages open
7. Select **Export as** in the File menu
8. Select your preferred file type by extension (say png) below the dialog box that pops up.
9. Click on **Export** to export your image to your desired location.
10. You can then check your file explorer for the exported image.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: The question is for ImageMagick using a command line, not for Gimp using a graphical interface.

Answer (score 0):

I use [icepdf](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEpdf/overview.jsf) an open source java pdf engine. Check the [office demo](http://icepdf-viewer.icesoft.org/icepdf-viewer/icepdfViewer.jsf).

```
package image2pdf;

import org.icepdf.core.exceptions.PDFException;
import org.icepdf.core.exceptions.PDFSecurityException;
import org.icepdf.core.pobjects.Document;
import org.icepdf.core.pobjects.Page;
import org.icepdf.core.util.GraphicsRenderingHints;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class pdf2image {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Document document = new Document();
      try {
         document.setFile("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\test.pdf");
      } catch (PDFException ex) {
         System.out.println("Error parsing PDF document " + ex);
      } catch (PDFSecurityException ex) {
         System.out.println("Error encryption not supported " + ex);
      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
         System.out.println("Error file not found " + ex);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
         System.out.println("Error IOException " + ex);
      }

      // save page captures to file.
      float scale = 1.0f;
      float rotation = 0f;

      // Paint each pages content to an image and
      // write the image to file
      for (int i = 0; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
         try {
         BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) document.getPageImage(
             i, GraphicsRenderingHints.PRINT, Page.BOUNDARY_CROPBOX, rotation, scale);

         RenderedImage rendImage = image;
         try {
            System.out.println(" capturing page " + i);
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\test_imageCapture1_" + i + ".png");
            ImageIO.write(rendImage, "png", file);
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         image.flush();
         }catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }

      // clean up resources
      document.dispose();
   }
}
```

I've also tried [imagemagick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605085/6521116) and [pdftoppm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30560120/6521116), both pdftoppm and icepdf has a high resolution than imagemagick.

Answer (score 0):

Many answers here concentrate on using magick (or its dependency GhostScript) as set by the OP question, with a few  suggesting Gimp as an alternative, without describing why some settings may work best for different cases.

Taking the OP "sample" the requirement is a crisp trimmed image as small as possible yet retaining good readability. and here **the result is 96 dpi in 58 KB (a very small increase on the vector source 54 KB)** yet retains a good image even zoomed in. compare that with 72 dpi (226 KB) in the accepted answer image above.

[image]

The key point is any image processor can be scripted to batch run from the command line using a profile as input, so here IrfanView (with or without GS) is set to auto crop the pdf page(s) and output at a default 96 dpi to PNG using only 4 BitPerPixel colour for 16 shades of greys.
The size could be further reduced by dropping resolution to 72 but 96 is an optimal setting for PNG screen display.

Answer (score -1):

Use this commandline:

```
convert -geometry 3600x3600 -density 300x300 -quality 100 TEAM\ 4.pdf team4.png
```

This should correctly convert the file as you've asked for.

Answer (score -1):

The following python script will work on any Mac (Snow Leopard and upward). It can be used on the command line with successive PDF files as arguments, or you can put in into a Run Shell Script action in Automator, and make a Service (Quick Action in Mojave).

You can set the resolution of the output image in the script.

The [script](https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/blob/master/Automator_Scripts/pdf2png.py) and a [Quick Action](https://github.com/benwiggy/PDFsuite/blob/master/Quick_Actions/PDF%202%20PNG.workflow.zip) can be downloaded from github.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import os, sys
import Quartz as Quartz
from LaunchServices import (kUTTypeJPEG, kUTTypeTIFF, kUTTypePNG, kCFAllocatorDefault) 

resolution = 300.0 #dpi
scale = resolution/72.0

cs = Quartz.CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(Quartz.kCGColorSpaceSRGB)
whiteColor = Quartz.CGColorCreate(cs, (1, 1, 1, 1))
# Options: kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast (no trans), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast 
transparency = Quartz.kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast

#Save image to file
def writeImage (image, url, type, options):
    destination = Quartz.CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url, type, 1, None)
    Quartz.CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image, options)
    Quartz.CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)
    return

def getFilename(filepath):
    i=0
    newName = filepath
    while os.path.exists(newName):
        i += 1
        newName = filepath + " %02d"%i
    return newName

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        pdf = Quartz.CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(Quartz.CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(filename))
        numPages = Quartz.CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf)
        shortName = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
        prefix = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]
        folderName = getFilename(shortName)
        try:
            os.mkdir(folderName)
        except:
            print "Can't create directory '%s'"%(folderName)
            sys.exit()

        # For each page, create a file
        for i in range (1, numPages+1):
            page = Quartz.CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, i)
            if page:
        #Get mediabox
                mediaBox = Quartz.CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, Quartz.kCGPDFMediaBox)
                x = Quartz.CGRectGetWidth(mediaBox)
                y = Quartz.CGRectGetHeight(mediaBox)
                x *= scale
                y *= scale
                r = Quartz.CGRectMake(0,0,x, y)
        # Create a Bitmap Context, draw a white background and add the PDF
                writeContext = Quartz.CGBitmapContextCreate(None, int(x), int(y), 8, 0, cs, transparency)
                Quartz.CGContextSaveGState (writeContext)
                Quartz.CGContextScaleCTM(writeContext, scale,scale)
                Quartz.CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(writeContext, whiteColor)
                Quartz.CGContextFillRect(writeContext, r)
                Quartz.CGContextDrawPDFPage(writeContext, page)
                Quartz.CGContextRestoreGState(writeContext)
        # Convert to an "Image"
                image = Quartz.CGBitmapContextCreateImage(writeContext) 
        # Create unique filename per page
                outFile = folderName +"/" + prefix + " %03d.png"%i
                url = Quartz.CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(kCFAllocatorDefault, outFile, len(outFile), False)
        # kUTTypeJPEG, kUTTypeTIFF, kUTTypePNG
                type = kUTTypePNG
        # See the full range of image properties on Apple's developer pages.
                options = {
                    Quartz.kCGImagePropertyDPIHeight: resolution,
                    Quartz.kCGImagePropertyDPIWidth: resolution
                    }
                writeImage (image, url, type, options)
                del page
```

Comment: Presumably downvoted because python's been removed. Sadly, one can no longer rely on python3 and pyobjc being installed, so this whole method goes in the bin. It is possible to use Swift as a scripting language, but it's no fun.

Answer (score -1):

get Image from Pdf in iOS Swift Best solution

```
func imageFromPdf(pdfUrl : URL,atIndex index : Int, closure:@escaping((UIImage)->Void)){
    
    autoreleasepool {
        
        // Instantiate a `CGPDFDocument` from the PDF file's URL.
        guard let document = PDFDocument(url: pdfUrl) else { return }
        
        // Get the first page of the PDF document.
        guard let page = document.page(at: index) else { return }
        
        // Fetch the page rect for the page we want to render.
        let pageRect = page.bounds(for: .mediaBox)
        
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: pageRect.size)
        let img = renderer.image { ctx in
            // Set and fill the background color.
            UIColor.white.set()
            ctx.fill(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageRect.width, height: pageRect.height))
            
            // Translate the context so that we only draw the `cropRect`.
            ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: -pageRect.origin.x, y: pageRect.size.height - pageRect.origin.y)
            
            // Flip the context vertically because the Core Graphics coordinate system starts from the bottom.
            ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
            
            // Draw the PDF page.
            page.draw(with: .mediaBox, to: ctx.cgContext)
        }
        closure(img)

    }
    
    
}
```

//Usage

```
    let pdfUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "PDF URL")
    self.imageFromPdf2(pdfUrl: pdfUrl, atIndex: 0) { imageIS in
        
    }
```

Comment: The question is how to do it with ImageMagick's `convert`.

Answer (score -2):

It's actually pretty easy to do with Preview on a mac.  All you have to do is open the file in Preview and save-as (or export) a png or jpeg but make sure that you use at least 300 dpi at the bottom of the window to get a high quality image.

Comment: Can this be automated if you have thousands of pages?

Answer (score -2):

You can do it in **LibreOffice Draw** (which is usually preinstalled in **Ubuntu**):

1. Open PDF file in LibreOffice Draw.
2. Scroll to the page you need.
3. **Make sure** text/image elements are placed correctly. If not, you can adjust/edit them on the page.
4. Top menu: File > Export...
5. Select the image format you need in the bottom-right menu. I recommend PNG.
6. Name your file and click Save.
7. Options window will appear, so you can adjust resolution and size.
8. Click OK, and you are done.

Answer (score -3):

Imagemagick provides the convert tool that can be used to do various complicated image processing tasks.

Convert All Pages of PDF File to Images
Use **convert** to convert PDF pages to images with the following command:

```
convert -density 150 presentation.pdf -quality 90 output-%3d.jpg
```

Convert PDF to Image with high resolution In (PHP)Laravel using Imagick.

```
 $pdf_path = Storage::disk('public')->path($product_asset->pdf_path);
 $directory_create = Storage::disk('public')->path('products/'.$product- 
 >id.'/pdf_images');
 if (!file_exists($directory_create)) {
    mkdir($directory_create, 0777, true);
 }

 $output_images = $directory_create.'/';

 $im = new Imagick();
 $im->setResolution(250, 250);
 $im->readImage($pdf_path);
 $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
 $im->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
 $im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
 $im->setCompressionQuality(100);
 $im->clear();
 $im->destroy();
```

Answer (score -4):

this works for **creating a single file from multiple PDF's and images files:**

```
php exec('convert -density 300 -trim "/path/to/input_filename_1.png" "/path/to/input_filename_2.pdf" "/path/to/input_filename_3.png" -quality 100 "/path/to/output_filename_0.pdf"');
```

WHERE:

-density 300 = dpi

-trim = something about transparancy - makes edges look smooth, it seems

-quality 100 = quality vs compression (100 % quality)

-flatten ... for multi page, do not use "flatten"