# Convert Multip Page PDF in to single pages with PHP, Imagick ghost script

Tags: php, unix, ghostscript, imagick

i have a pdf upload script with php, my question is when user uploads a multipage pdf file , i want this to split in to individual pdf's. for instance if the pdf has 3 pages, the result should be 1.pdf , 2.pdf, 3.pdf etc.

for example 
convert -density 300 filename.pdf filename.png   works fine creating a png file , but i want the same in to pdf files.

Comment: anything i could find.

Comment: Don't use Imagick for this. Just call Ghostscript directly - something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085550/php-imagick-pdf-conversion-text-aliasing/23144243#23144243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) and [FPDI](http://www.setasign.com/products/fpdi/about/) to do this.

```
require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('fpdi/fpdi.php');

// get the page count
$pdf = new FPDI();
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($pdfFilePath);

// iterate through all pages
for($pageNumber = 1; $pageNumber <= $pageCount; $pageNumber++)
{
    // create blank document
    $pdf = new FPDI();

    // import a page
    $pdf->setSourceFile($pdfFilePath);
    $templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNumber);

    // get the size of the imported page
    $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

    // create a page (landscape or portrait depending on the page being imported)
    if($size['w'] > $size['h'])
    {
        $pdf->AddPage('L', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
    }
    else
    {   $pdf->AddPage('P', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
    }

    // use the imported page
    $pdf->useTemplate($templateId);

    // write the PDF file
    $pdf->Output(('/path/to/save/'.$pageNumber.'pdf'), 'F');
}
```

Comment: that is good idea, will try it but should be working . thank you

Comment: yes tried and tested it . works like a charm with little twigs