# Php imagick anti aliasing

Tags: php, imagick

I have a problem with my php: when I make conversion `PDF` to `JPG` not shown correctly.

This is the original pictures of pdf - > http://s16.postimg.org/ma0jizgt1/text_problem2_fw.png

This is the jpg after converting with imagick - > http://s14.postimg.org/ilhs9tt3l/text_problem_fw.png

Please can you help me ?

Thank you

**PHP:**

```
if (move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"], $uploadUrlPdf . $_FILES["files"]["name"]))
{

    $_FILES['files']['name'];
    $nr_pag = $_POST['nr_pagini'];

    for($i = 0; $i < $nr_pag; $i++)
    {

        $fn = $uploadUrlSwf.sprintf("%02d", "$i").".jpg";

        if (!file_exists($fn)) 
        {
            $im = new imagick();

            $im->setResolution($dpi,$dpi);
            $pdf = $uploadUrlPdf.$_FILES['files']['name']."[$i]";
            $im->readimage($pdf); 

            $im->setImageFormat('jpg');
            $im->writeImage($fn);
            file_put_contents( $fn, (string)$im );
            $im->clear(); 
            $im->destroy();
        }

    }
}
else
{     
    echo "error!";
}
```

Comment: It's possible you're using a version of ImageMagick (or rather Ghostscript) that has a bug in it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23085550/php-imagick-pdf-conversion-text-aliasing/23144243#23144243

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your dpi value higher. If that does not work, try another export format (other than jpg). SVG would be your best bet, because you can scale that while the text and other shapes are still perfect quality. JPG wil not be sharp at a high zoom level if the resolution (dpi) is too low.

This forum entry might help: [anti-aliased text when exporting PDF to image](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/533056?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: I need only jpg or png. Now the dpi is $dpi = 200 .

Comment: No difference, only size of jpg.