# Display PDF(stored as a BLOB) as an image in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, partial-views, actionresult, filecontentresult

I have to display a PDF(stored as BLOB in SQL Server table) in a partial view. I am doing the same for a ".jpeg" image stored as BLOB in the table.The image is getting displayed,however,the PDF isnt.I have the following code in my controller:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Show3LeadImage(int id)
{
    Byte[] imageData = null;
    using (var scope = new PatientPersistenceScope())
    {
         searchRequest leadRequest = new searchRequest();
         leadRequest.CaseNumber = id;
         var mrx12LeadBitmap = _mrxSearchService.Get12Lead(leadRequest);
         imageData = mrx12LeadBitmap.Data12Leads[0].mrx3Lead;
         scope.Done();
    }
   return File(imageData,"image/png");//I have tried "FileContentResult,but it didnt work
 }
```

The code in the partial view(.ascx) looks like this:

```
<object data='<%= Url.Action("Show3LeadImage", "CareRecord", new { id = Model.CareRecord.CaseNumber}) %>' type="application/pdf" style="width: 721px; height: 800px;" ></object>
```

I do not have access to the physical file....the BLOB is all I have.

Is it even possible to display a PDF as image in partial view? I came across lots of articles that explained how to make a PDF available for download in the partial view.But I do not want my file to be downloadable. Is this functionality achievable or am I trying to do something impossible?

Comment: You can achieve it easily by placing your pdf on disk and keeping its path in sql. I guess,that will lower down the SQL read/write times.

Answer (score 1):

Converting a PDF to image is not as simple as serving it as a PNG. You will need to convert it using a library, like ImageMagick or ABCPdf (sample: [Convert PDF to image with high resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605006/convert-pdf-to-image-with-high-resolution))

If you want to embed the PDF inside the HTML the are several ways to do it, i.e. [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)