# Extract plots from PDFs

Tags: image, pdf, image-processing, plot

We have a pdf page which contains one or more figures which are two-dimensional plots of experimental results. The figures may or may not be embedded in text. Each plot has the x and y axis with their labels and unit measurements marked in the plot. Inside each figure are one or more plots, each with a different color.

How can we convert the plot into a table of corresponding x and y values (say for 100 points) ?

I have already tried [WebPlotDigitizer](http://arohatgi.info/WebPlotDigitizer) but it works only when the input is a standalone picture of a plot.

What I think I'll have to do is extract the plots from the PDF and process it further. Now, I am not able to find a tool for doing that. I have attached a [sample PDF](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ow2eXsuRl-TnhWeldaN2FFbE0/view?usp=sharing) from which the plots have to be extracted.

Note that the 2 plots in the last page of the PDF are images and can be extracted readily(I've found a couple of software for those).The other plots are not images and the software are not able to extract them.

Is there any open source software that can achieve that?

Comment: You can convert each page to a PNG or TIFF file with `ImageMagick` and then cut out the plots and send them to WebPlotDigitiser obviously, but I suspect you don't mean that, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plots in this PDF file you have provided are made with vector drawings, so the only way to extract them is to convert PDF into image (i.e. render pages). Try [ImageMagick's convert command line](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php), see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605085/712093)

Answer (score 0):

As Photoshop is very well scriptable, it is actually possible to extract images from a PDF programmatically (as opposed to pages; see Photoshop JavaScript documentation).

Then you have the whole set of instruments to adjust the images, so that further processing (interpretation) is easier to accomplish.