# How can I edit a pdf in Ubuntu 20.04 (for free)?

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to be able to add text and copy images into a pdf (in Ubuntu) and save the edited pdf.

I have looked around quite a bit and have found the solutions wanting

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this in 4 steps.

1 - convert pdf into jpg from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61700520/615379)

This is the command

```
    pdftoppm -jpeg -r 300 your.pdf output
```

2 - edit <output*.jpg> with KolourPaint (or another image editor) and add text or images as desired

3 - open the just edited file (<output*.jpg>) with LibreOffice Draw

4 - Finally, choose 'Export as PDF' option to output the  file as a pdf

There, you now have a PDF editor for Ubuntu.

Note, that in a pinch, when you have to sign a document (but don't have a printer/scanner handy), you can take a picture of your signature, share it with yourself and then paste it into the document that needs a signature. This allows you to sign a PDF without having to print it out